# In a list, combine all files into a single file

Tags: list

We have a need to have a template for a powerpoint, where each employee would have to fill out 3-5 slides.    I created a Sharepoint list, which would list out each employee, and the employee would attach their file to the list.

Is there anyway to merge all the powerpoint files back into a single file from the Sharepoint list once every employee updates the list and attaches their file?

Would like a solution, or to know if there's another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as if a SharePoint Slide Library is almost what you describe see [Publishing and reusing PowerPoint content using Slide Library](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/09/24/publishing-and-reusing-content-using-slide-library.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I can look into it, but seems like you need office 2010, and our office is still on 2007 and not likely to go 2010 soon.  Thanks!